# Is it possible to make django admin field filter with another fields data in same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to generate models field date with another field with replace spaces with '-' on typing

When i with write foo **title** field, **slug** field automatically get data from title field and replace **space** with **-**

**Is it possible?**

Thank you

```
class foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your app's admin.py to the code below.

admin.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from .models import Foo #It is good design practice to start uppercase template names

   class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         list_display = ['title', 'slug'] #lists the columns in admin
         search_fields = ['title', 'slug'] #filter options
         ordering = ['title'] # select by which field to sort

    admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

This should enable search in your admin.